# API call switching to Oauth 2.0 with openid

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, oauth, etl, twinfield

I used to query my financial data through Power Query in Power BI. Recently I've switched to doing it through a python script running on Google Cloud functions, triggered by Cloud Scheduler. (is this the best way?) It saves a csv file to GCStorage.

The party that provides the data I'm after is switching to oAuth 2.0 using either **implicit** or **authorization code** flow. I believe this means that somewhere in this flow a browser is opened where username and password must be entered. Also I need to give a redirect uri to this party, I'm not sure how to implement this in my current setup.

Anyone have an idea? More info about the API can be found here. https://accounting.twinfield.com/webservices/documentation/#/ApiReference/Authentication/OpenIdConnect

Answer (score 1):

Usually the Authorization Code flow would be the way to go in your kind of application.

1. You will send a authentication request to their API(redirecting the user). They will authenticate the User and redirect the user back to your application, using the redirect URI you provided.
2. You can get an access token or ID token from their token endpoint using the code, your client id and your client secret.